# Multiple instance of same block and contextual widget

Tags: 8, navigation

I print the same menu twice in my region (to handle responsive design).

Here is a part of my region--header.html.twig with my two `topnavigation` menus:

```
 <div class="header-main-top-wrapper">
    <div class="nav-secondary">
       {{ topnavigation }}
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="menu-main--dropdown-wrapper">
    <div class="nav-secondary">
       {{ topnavigation }}
    </div>
 </div>
```

My problem is the contextual module is not able to show contextual links for these two blocks (it works if I disable one of them).
If I inspect the DOM, they have the same `data-contextual-id` value so maybe it's a problem for the rendering.

Comment: Do you have menu in block?

Comment: Yes my menu are rendered with the default block system

Comment: Your best bet would be using a context module https://www.drupal.org/project/context. Once you have module installed you can have the same block display in two different regions and the module will take care of assigning proper id and making contextual links available.

Comment: Hum, I could try context module but my block menu is only present once in block layout and in one region. I print my menu twice in my html.twig.

Comment: You can print the same block twice using context module. You just have to create two contexts for it.

Comment: Why don't you just create two blocks, which is trivial to do? That said, pretty sure there are issues that contextual links only work for unique entities, the same applies to nodes and everything else that can be contextually edited